# If statement creating unwanted objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason this if statement creates a GameObject in Unity when run.

```
if (touchedTarget == true && Targeter[1] == new GameObject()) {
    _destination = Targeter[1].transform;
}
```

There is nothing else in the script that creates an object. I thought that this would compare the thing in the array to a new GameObject and I'm utterly confused by what is going on.

With the new GameObject(): https://gyazo.com/6e7c5fe524d0425b4474b54cfe79ac19
Without: https://gyazo.com/6ed97637e2e2765f6ef4a976bfb6071a

Can someone explain why it did this?

Comment: a likely culprit is the `new GameObject()`. Are you trying to check if `Targeter[1]` is an object with all default values?

Comment: Is the `==` operator overridden in `GameObject` to compare properties? Maybe the `if` statement is checking to see if `Targeter[1]` has all the default values of `GameObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second condition of that if statement, `Targeter[1] == new GameObject()`, specifically the right side of it, is instantiating a new `GameObject` each time it is run.

If you simply want to check if the `Targeter[1]` object has default value, you could consider implementing a new method which checks the fields of the `GameObject`, to determine if the fields match the defaults.

Comment: I think doing `default(GameObject)` would work for comparing to a default object, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I believe `default(GameObject)` would simply be `null` would it not?

Comment: I've no clue. I would've tested it before I commented but my workstation doesn't have Unity on it.

Comment: `default(object)` returns `null` for reference types, so I'm fairly certain `GameObject` would give the same result

Comment: Yes, `default(GameObject)` returns `null`.